# Java Pass by Reference/Value

Tags: java, pass-by-reference-value

I have read and (believe I have) understood the posts made previously on this forum.

However as a Java novice I am having an issue

I create a  MAP voucherDetails and pass it into a function where it is being populated (verified with trace). On return iy is empty. Why?

```
Map<String, Object> voucherDetails=new LinkedHashMap<>();
log.info("B4: "+voucherDetails.size());   // size is 0  
log.info("B4: "+voucherDetails.toString());     // {}
if (!ws.handleVoucherDetailsResponse(voucherDetails)){
    return false;
}
log.info("AF: "+voucherDetails.toString()); //{}
log.info("AF: "+voucherDetails.size());     // size is 0


public boolean handleVoucherDetailsResponse(Map<String, Object> voucher) throws IOException {
    log.enter("handleDetailsDetailsResponse");

    PCVMResponseType status=decodeResponse();
    switch (status) {       
    case DATA:
        voucher=decodeVoucherDetailsResponse(response);
        String accountno=(String)voucher.get("accountno");
        log.info("AA: "+accountno);
        String voucherno=(String)voucher.get("voucherno");
        log.info("VV: "+voucherno);         
        log.info("CC: "+voucher.size());
        log.info("IN: "+voucher.toString());            
        return true;
    default:
        return false;           
    }       
}
```

although voucher is being populated inside the function it is still empy on return. As if the Object is being passed not as a pointer to it.

What am I doing wrong and how do I do it correctly

TIA

Ephraim

Comment: Please provide [mcve].

Comment: Gonna be hard to say without the code of `handleVoucherDetailsResponse` ...

Comment: This is not a forum.

Answer (score 2):

`voucher=decodeVoucherDetailsResponse(response);` does not update the caller's reference. You can't update the caller's reference without returning a new `Map`. However, you can add all the key-value pairs from the second `Map` to the first. Like,

```
voucher.putAll(decodeVoucherDetailsResponse(response));
```

If you want to remove all of the existing values as well, call `voucher.clear();` before `putAll()`.

Comment: So what does voucher=decodeVoucherDetailsResponse(response); actually do? It appears to have updated a map as the debug misleadinfly shows. What was updated?

Comment: The *local* reference in `handleVoucherDetailsResponse`, not the reference passed to `handleVoucherDetailsResponse`. Java is **always** pass by value, and you can't update the original caller's value (without returning and assigning, as you did with `decodeVoucherDetailsResponse`).

Answer (score 0):

Here is how java works:
All your integer, char, etc. variables are just plane values
All your objects variables are references

Here:

```
voucher=decodeVoucherDetailsResponse(response);
```

in function   `handleVoucherDetailsResponse()`  you set your `voucher` variable to the reference of the new object, returned by `decodeVoucherDetailsResponse()` .

So now you have two objects:
One that is referenced outside of the function (Empty)
And another that is referenced inside the function (Has data)

The way you should do that is to pass the `voucher` variable to the function, that will populate it.

If the Map is still empty, then there is a problem in `decodeVoucherDetailsResponse()` function.

Hope this helps you,
-Mk Km